# Ractive and dynamic form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, serialization, ractivejs

I am trying to create a dynamic form using Ractive (0.9.x). An input tag should have in the value attribute a variable name to be bound to the current instance of Ractive. In my case, I don't have values at the start. My form should be empty and dynamic. My goal is to serialize data in JSON Object.

```
{{# keys:key }}
    <div class="ks-form-keyword">
    <label>{{this}}</label>
    <input name="{{this}}" value="" >
  </div>                   
{{/}}
```

Here's a fiddle to explain my issue : https://jsfiddle.net/alibenmessaoud/k35az616/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in your `data` you have a new field to collect the form data as JSON eg. `formData:{}`

Then simply changing your `<input name="{{this}}" value="" />` to `<input value="{{formData[this]}}" name="{{this}}" />` should do the trick.

Result from clicking Go, after filling in a value for `uid`:

`{"uid":"someTestValueByUser","header.category":"","header.priority":"","from":"","id":"","to":"","header.group":"","timestamp":""}`

ps. I am not sure if you need `name="{{this}}"`. If you're not submitting the form itself, then that can go.

Lastly herewith an [updated JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k35az616/13/)